# How to merge UIView from "snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates" and create Video

Tags: ios, swift, screenshot

Is there any way to merge all UIView returned from function "snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates" and create a video from them?

Currently i am taking screenshot of screen in Timer event using below code

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.10, target: self, selector: NSSelectorFromString("screenshotTimerEvent"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

// Timer event function to capture screenshot and add in Array

```
func screenshotTimerEvent()
{
    self.arrImagesScreenShots.addObject(self.view.snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(true))
}
```

Then after that when the recording is stopped i use below code to show all those screenshots as a video.

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.10, target: self, selector: NSSelectorFromString("showImages"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

// In this function i am adding uiview from start to end so it shows like a video is playing

```
func showImages()
{
    oldView.removeFromSuperview()
    if(arrImagesScreenShots.count > count)
    {
        oldView = arrImagesScreenShots.objectAtIndex(count) as! UIView
        self.view.addSubview(oldView)
        count += 1
    }
    else
    {
        timer.invalidate()
        count = 0
    }
}
```

I am not sure if this is the best way to do it but for now its working.
Next thing i want is to merge these UIView into a video and upload to server.

Is there any way?